# Python Pandas create new column in loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I'm attempting to create a new column for each column by dividing two columns. df is a pandas dataframe...

```
columns = list(df.columns.values)
for column_1 in columns: 
    for column_2 in columns:         
        new_column = '-'.join([column_1,column_2])
        df[new_column] = df[column_1] / df[column_2]
```

Getting an error: NotImplementedError: operator '/' not implemented for bool dtypes

Any thoughts would be appreciate?

Comment: One of the columns is a Boolean value.  Check the df.dytpes, and omit the columns that aren't numeric.

Comment: Thank you... I assumed bool would evaluate to 0 or 1. Clearly it does not.

Comment: I would try to convert both columns to  float, and catch any errors from the attempted conversion. If Python can cast to float, it's probably fair game to go ahead with the division. This also prevents any integer division weirdness.

Answer (score 3):

Like Brian said you're definitely trying to divide non-numeric columns. Here's a working example of dividing two columns to create a third:

```
name = ['bob','sam','joe']
age = [25,32,50]
wage = [50000, 75000, 32000]

people = {}
for i in range(0,3):
    people[i] = {'name':name[i], 'age':age[i],'wage':wage[i]}

# you should now have a data frame where each row is a person
# you have one string column (name), and two numerics (age and wage)        
df = pd.DataFrame(people).transpose()

df['wage_per_year'] = df['wage']/df['age']

print df
```